# Wpf designer doesn't works correctly

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2022

**when i debug my wpf project, this exception occurred and the wpf designer doesn't load.**[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6QWL2.png)

System.Resources.MissingSatelliteAssemblyException
The satellite assembly named "Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.SurfaceDesigner.resources.dll, Version=17.0.0.0, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d5a3a" for the "en" rescue culture cannot be found or could not be loaded. This is usually due to an installation problem. Consider reinstalling or repairing the application.
to System.Resources.ManifestBasedResourceGroveler.HandleSatelliteMissing()
to System.Resources.ManifestBasedResourceGroveler.GrovelForResourceSet(CultureInfo culture, Dictionary`2 localResourceSets, Boolean tryParents, Boolean createIfNotExists, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) to System.Resources.ResourceManager.InternalGetResourceSet(CultureInfo requestedCulture, Boolean createIfNotExists, Boolean tryParents, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) to System.Resources.ResourceManager.InternalGetResourceSet(CultureInfo culture, Boolean createIfNotExists, Boolean tryParents) to System.Resources.ResourceManager.GetString(String name, CultureInfo culture) to System.Linq.Enumerable.ToDictionary[TSource,TKey,TElement](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 keySelector, Func`2 elementSelector, IEqualityComparer`1 compare)
to Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.SurfaceDesigner.DesignerTapStringTable.GetStringTableT
to Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.WpfSurfaceDesigner.Views.WpfSurfaceProcessContext.GetDesignerTapStringTable()
to Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.SurfaceDesigner.Documents.SurfaceIsolation.SurfaceProcessContext.InitializePipeline()
to Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.SurfaceDesigner.Documents.SurfaceIsolation.SurfaceProcessContext.FinishSurfaceProcessCreation(DateTime start, Boolean forcePlatformOnly)
to Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.SurfaceDesigner.Documents.SurfaceIsolation.SurfaceProcessContext.d__105.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from the previous location at which the exception was thrown ---
to System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
to System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
to Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.XamlSurfaceDesigner.Views.IsolatedSurfaceImageHost.d__67.MoveNext()

System.AggregateException
One or more errors occurred.

Please help me.

Comment: Judging from the screenshot your system is in French, and judging from the exception the English resource pack for the designer isn't installed. "This is usually due to an installation problem. Consider reinstalling or repairing the application", so try reinstalling the WPF designer

Comment: I have tried to reinstall and repare visual studio but it still doesn't works , how Can reinstall designer please ?